# Excel - copy Row to Column , ADDED MORE DETAILS

Tags: excel

I tried transpose where I like 1 row for Client and Attribute across. but it's giving me all attribute across (in columns) without keeping the Client in tack. It should look like this afterwards

[image]

Client column 1 column 2 column 3 column 4 column 5 New Client Accounting Legal work Screencasts Training Tutorials Envato Tutorials

When I select and use Excel's transpose I get following.
[image]

But it should look like below (manually created)
[image]

Comment: Why negative vote? I provided all the info including screen shots. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer using Pivot table where show text in the values area. Here is the article that helped.

https://excel.officetuts.net/examples/show-text-in-pivot-values-area/